# Use python to export excel data for table in random location

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I keep receiving excel files where the table starts in a random location and I want to use python to export the data. I want to pull two columns from the table, but since the start location is random (example: one file the table might start on Column 2 Row 3 and the next time we receive the file the table starts on Column 4 Row 7).

I tried trimming the null values, but sometimes the file has a title so that doesn't work.

The table column is consistent so I was wondering if there's any way to use the index of that column to pull the data.

Below is an example of the data I'm receiving. I want to pull the columns Product Number and Market. The table is in random locations in each file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Fun.xlsx')

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
            Position = df.iloc[i][j] == "Product Number"
            if Position == True:
                print(i,j)

correctdata = pd.read_excel('Fun.xlsx', skiprows=(i-1))
FinalCorrectData = correctdata[["Product Number", "Sale", "Market"]]
```

This gets you the data frame you need (FinalCorrectData) you may have to worry about empty rows below the table, but that should be an easy fix. Once you have the data frame you can easily write it to an excel.

This is a naïve brute force way to solve this, so there probably is a better way to approach it.